# What is a countably infinite-dimensional coordinate space called and where can I read more about it?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, terminology

This is just a question about terminology. I'm interested in spaces of vectors with countably many components $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots)$ where each $x_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$. What are these spaces called? On Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_vector_spaces#Infinite_coordinate_space) they are referred to just as "Infinite coordinate space" but this term hasn't been very helpful when put into a Google search.

More specifically, I want to see what is known about linear algebra type problems when the vector lengths are countably infinite. Is there a name for this topic? Can you recommend good introductory books?

Comment: The wikipedia article titled [sequence space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) seems to be a better fit for what you want. In class these spaces are often called "little elle-p spaces", but for googling purposes this looks like it would be a good start: [l^p space sequences](http://www.google.com/search?q=l%5Ep+space+sequences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The countably-infinite-dimensional generalization of Euclidean space is $l^{2}$, and is a Hilbert Space. This space is named after the Mathematician who initiated the first serious study of such a space around 1905. The sequences $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots)$ are assumed to satisfy $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}|^{2} < \infty$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space

Answer (score 0):

To quote the Wikipedia article [you linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_vector_spaces#Infinite_coordinate_space):

> Infinite coordinate space: Let $F^\infty$ denote the space of infinite sequences of elements from $F$ such that only finitely many elements are nonzero. That is, if we write an element of $F^∞$ as $$x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$$ then only a finite number of the $x_i$ are nonzero (i.e., the coordinates become all zero after a certain point).

If you are really interested in this space:

- Such sequence are sometimes called [sequences with finite support](https://www.google.com/search?q=sequences+%22finite+support%22).
- Many authors [denote this space by $c_{00}$](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sequence+space%22+%22c00%22). In fact, you can find some posts on this where [this notation is used](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22c_%7B00%7D%22).